# Python & Pandas: How to do conditional calculation

Tags: python, pandas

`df['direction']` is the number of direction of the wind, ranging from 1-16. I want to convert it into `360-degree system`. 
`#1` direction is `90`, and `#2` is `67.5`, they run in clockwise.

I can do`df['degree'] = 90-(df.direction-1)*22.5`, but this would produce `negative value`, you can see the output below
[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP38W.png)

But I don't know how to use the `conditional` here, for `df['degree']<0, then + 360`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`df['degree'] = df['degree'].apply(lambda x: x + 360 if x < 0 else x)`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then you want the following:

```
In [36]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'direction':np.random.randint(1,17,20)})
df
Out[36]:
    direction
0          13
1          12
2           4
3           5
4          16
5           6
6           3
7          16
8          12
9           2
10         14
11         13
12          8
13          9
14          8
15         12
16          9
17          2
18          7
19          8
In [37]:

df['degrees'] = (90 - (df['direction'] -1) * 22.5)
df.loc[df['degrees']<0,'degrees'] += 360.0
df
Out[37]:
    direction  degrees
0          13    180.0
1          12    202.5
2           4     22.5
3           5      0.0
4          16    112.5
5           6    337.5
6           3     45.0
7          16    112.5
8          12    202.5
9           2     67.5
10         14    157.5
11         13    180.0
12          8    292.5
13          9    270.0
14          8    292.5
15         12    202.5
16          9    270.0
17          2     67.5
18          7    315.0
19          8    292.5
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not the `abs`, you can only + or - 360 degree, `50` and `-50` is qutie different.

Comment: OK, you can use a boolean mask after generating the column to conditionally add 360 to the negative values

Answer (score 1):

Short way to solve your problem will be using modulo.

```
df['degree'] = (90-(df.direction-1)*22.5)%360
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.loc` for conditional indexing

```
df.loc[ df.degree < 0 , 'degree'] += 360
```

Answer (score 0):

Use df[degree]<0 as condition statement:

```
df[degree] += (df[degree]<0) * 360
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.